# Compress embedded Javascript in HTML markup

Tags: javascript, compression, minify, yui-compressor

If you have a separate `.js` file, you may simply compress it with tools such as [Yahoo YUI Compressor.](http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/)

But, how can I compress embedded Javascript in every pages in my project?

(Copying the Javascript to a separate file, then compress, and then copy back to my page cannot be a professional solution for obvious reasons for a medium or big project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally have a build process which turns the source into a deployable form. This would include any compilation, unit tests, compression etc.

YUI compressor has a build tool for just that http://yuilibrary.com/download/builder/

Also check out ANT http://ant.apache.org/

Answer (score -1):

You could run a backend process that parses your html files, extracts the javascript code and inserts the compressed one. But in any case I would recommend you to seperate all your js into js files. This is it will be easier for you to maintenance in the future.

Comment: Well, but how to perform the 'backend process' you mentioned? Any tools available for that? If I have to write custom code for that, then it will be a tedious task!